# using custom command from old .inputrc in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I used to have this in my `.inputrc` when I used bash but it doesn't work in ZSH because ZSH doesn't read the .inputrc (AFAIK):

```
$if Bash
  # Meta+O can be made to load the previous 
  # command and position the cursor for typing an option
  "\eo": "\C-p\C-a\ef "
```

It's the one thing I miss from my bash days.  Is there a way to port this command to ZSH?  I tried some bindkey shenanigans with little success.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's right, `zsh` has its own line editor (`ZLE`) and doesn't read `readline`'s `.inputrc`.

Try:

```
# define widget function
function cursor-after-first-word {
    zle up-history
    zle beginning-of-line
    zle forward-word
    RBUFFER=" $RBUFFER"
}

# create widget from function
zle -N cursor-after-first-word

# bind widget to ESC-o
bindkey '^[o' cursor-after-first-word
```

See `man zshzle` about what else is possible.

Comment: Using `emacs-forward-word` instead of `forward-word` would better match how `forward-word` works in *bash* (and Emacs). Or the asker might want to redefine M-f and use a direct translation: `bindkey '^[f' emacs-forward-word; bindkey -s '^[o' '^p^a^[f '`