# Is it possible to use different zsh menu selection behaviour for different commands?

Tags: terminal, zsh, autocomplete

I'm using the `menu select` behaviour in `zsh`, which invokes a menu below the cursor where you can see the various possibilities. The .zshrc option i have set for this is

```
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=2
```

By default, pressing `Return` to select a possibility in this menu only completes the word — it does not actually send the command. For example, I might get a menu like this

```
~ % cd de<TAB>
completing directory:
[Desktop/]  Development/
```

Pressing `Return` here will result in

```
~ % cd Desktop/
```

I then have to press `Return` a *second* time to actually send the command.

I can modify this behaviour to make it so that pressing `Return` both selects the completion **and** sends the command by doing this

```
bindkey -M menuselect '^M' .accept-line
```

However, there's a problem with this: sometimes I need to complete a file or directory *without* sending the command. For example, I might need to do `ln -s Desktop Desktop2` — with this `bindkey` behaviour, trying to complete Desktop will result in `ln -s Desktop/` being sent as the command, and obviously I don't want that.

I'm aware that just pressing space will let me get on with the command, but it's now a habit.
Given this, is there a way to make it so that only **some** commands let you press `Return` once (like `cd`), but all **other** commands require pressing it twice?

Comment: If the `.zshrc` file doesn't allow you to do so then the answer is simply going to be no, unless you adjust the source code yourself to support command-based behavior. But then you still have to define for which commands to do this, which on its own is way more tedious than just pressing an additional enter...

Answer (score 2):

If you really need this, theoretically you could set a function that checks the command you're executing, and complete or send the line.

Try something like this (untested):

```
commands=(ls cd)
# define widget function
function check-command {
    zle beginning-of-line
    zle forward-word
    RBUFFER=" $RBUFFER"
    if [[ ${commands[(r)$LBUFFER]} == $LBUFFER ]] ; then ; zle accept-line ; else; zle     end-of-line ; fi
}

# create widget from function
zle -N check-command

# bind widget
bindkey -M menuselect '^M' check-command
```

Source: [using custom command from old .inputrc in zsh?](https://superuser.com/questions/278802/using-custom-command-from-old-inputrc-in-zsh)

Answer (score -1):

Technically its not possible in the way you are asking. Don't know if there is any other way out